# Convert for loop to iterator in rust

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, functional-programming, iterator, traits

So, I am trying to build a vector of vectors of a custom type.I am trying to implement a default for it and was **successful** with a for loop.

```rust
let mut data: Vec<Vec<Cell>> = Vec::new();
    for _i in 0..63 {
        let mut row: Vec<Cell> = Vec::with_capacity(64);
        for _j in 0..63 {
            row.push(Cell::default())
        }
        data.push(row);
   }
```

I felt this code could do with some functional style and interators, so I decided to do something like so:

```rust
let data: Vec<Vec<Cell>> = Vec::with_capacity(64)
    .iter_mut()
    .map(|mut x: &mut Vec<Cell>| {
        x = Vec::with_capacity(64)
            .iter_mut()
            .map(|mut y: Cell| y = Cell::default())
            .collect()
        })
    .collect();
```

With this, I get an error like so:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in closure arguments
   --> src/types.rs:124:26
    |
124 |                         .map(|mut y: Cell| y = Cell::default())
    |                          ^^^ ------------- found signature defined here
    |                          |
    |                          expected due to this
    |
    = note: expected closure signature `fn(&mut _) -> _`
               found closure signature `fn(types::cell::Cell) -> _`
note: required by a bound in `map`
   --> /home/naitik/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/iter/traits/iterator.rs:779:12
    |
779 |         F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> B,
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `map`
```

I do not understand the problem here. What exactly is it? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Why are you assigning in a `map()?` The whole point of that is to emit new values. This code seems to make no sense. You get defaults already. You don't need to re-write that, at least if you ask for them via `vec![Cell::default(); 64]`.

Comment: @tadman The code does not make sense to me either. But I have no idea about the iterators. Doing `let data: Vec<Vec<Cell>> = Vec::with_capacity(64)` gives an empty list for `data`, not a list of the default values of `Cell`

Comment: It reserves that capacity. It does not fill it. From the documentation: "It is important to note that although the returned vector has the minimum capacity specified, **the vector will have a zero length**."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how `Vec::with_capacity` works. It doesn't actually put anything into a vec that you can iterate over and assign to. You want to map `Cell::default` over something and then collect that into a vec. That something doesn't matter, only that there's 64 of them, so a range will do:

```
let data: Vec<Vec<Cell>> = (0..64)
        .map(|_| (0..64).map(|_| Cell::default()).collect())
        .collect();
```

`collect` should hopefully figure out the needed capacities from the ranges' `TrustedLen` impl on its own to avoid unnecessary re-allocations.

I would, however, doubt that this is better than the procedural approach. It seems less clear and harder to modify to me. Just stick to good ol' for loops is my two cents.

If `Cell` is `Clone` or `Copy` you could even just do:

```
let data: Vec<Vec<Cell>> = vec![vec![Cell::default(); 64]; 64];
```

for maximal minimality.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly, collect() creates a new vector with all the values of the iterator and map is just iterating over the range?

Comment: `map()` creates the new values as an iterator. `collect()` converts that into its final form, in your case `Vec`. `map()` itself is an iterator that works on other iterators.

Comment: Yep. `map` yields `Cell::default()` for every iteration of the range, and `collect` collects them all into a vec.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for the help! No matter how many times I read the doc, I always make some stupid mistake, Hopefully I improve over time.

Comment: Rust is fairly unique in how it differentiates between *iteration* and *collection* while other languages like JavaScript and Ruby don't force you to pay as much attention.